# Compiling a dll with g++

Tags: c++, c, g++, linker-errors, undefined-reference

I've been trying to compile this projet on windows with g++:
https://github.com/newhouseb/openvr-c

My command lines:

```
g++ -c  -std=gnu++0x -DBUILDING_OPENVR_C openvr_c.cpp openvr_c.h
g++ -shared -o openvr_c.dll openvr_c.o  -std=gnu++0x -Wl,--out-implib,openvr_api.dll -L. -lopenvr_api
```

When i run the second line i get these errors:

> openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr14COpenVRContext10CheckClearEv[__ZN2vr14COpenVRContext10CheckClearEv]+0x12):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__VR_GetInitToken'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr14COpenVRContext10CheckClearEv[__ZN2vr14COpenVRContext10CheckClearEv]+0x33):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__VR_GetInitToken'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr14COpenVRContext8VRSystemEv[__ZN2vr14COpenVRContext8VRSystemEv]+0x2b):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__VR_GetGenericInterface'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr14COpenVRContext11VRChaperoneEv[__ZN2vr14COpenVRContext11VRChaperoneEv]+0x2c):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__VR_GetGenericInterface'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr14COpenVRContext16VRChaperoneSetupEv[__ZN2vr14COpenVRContext16VRChaperoneSetupEv]+0x2c):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__VR_GetGenericInterface'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr14COpenVRContext12VRCompositorEv[__ZN2vr14COpenVRContext12VRCompositorEv]+0x2c):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__VR_GetGenericInterface'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr14COpenVRContext9VROverlayEv[__ZN2vr14COpenVRContext9VROverlayEv]+0x2c):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__VR_GetGenericInterface'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr14COpenVRContext14VRRenderModelsEv[__ZN2vr14COpenVRContext14VRRenderModelsEv]+0x2c):
>   more undefined references to`_imp__VR_GetGenericInterface' follow
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr7VR_InitEPNS_12EVRInitErrorENS_18EVRApplicationTypeE[__ZN2vr7VR_InitEPNS_12EVRInitErrorENS_18EVRApplicationTypeE]+0x23):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__VR_InitInternal'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr7VR_InitEPNS_12EVRInitErrorENS_18EVRApplicationTypeE[__ZN2vr7VR_InitEPNS_12EVRInitErrorENS_18EVRApplicationTypeE]+0x4c):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__VR_IsInterfaceVersionValid'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr7VR_InitEPNS_12EVRInitErrorENS_18EVRApplicationTypeE[__ZN2vr7VR_InitEPNS_12EVRInitErrorENS_18EVRApplicationTypeE]+0x61):
>   undefined reference to `_imp__VR_ShutdownInternal'
>   openvr_c.o:openvr_c.cpp:(.text$_ZN2vr11VR_ShutdownEv[__ZN2vr11VR_ShutdownEv]+0x7):
>   undefined reference to`_imp__VR_ShutdownInternal' collect2.exe:
>   error: ld returned 1 exit status

I don't understand what are these errors,

Can someone enlighten me ?

Comment: This project is a set of C bindings to OpenVR. You need to link it against an OpenVR version built with gcc.

Comment: OpenVR is closed sources, i think it is build with visual studio.
If I want to compile the binding i will have to use the same compiler ?

Comment: Yes, you have to use the same compiler. g++ and VS have very different ABIs. The name mangling is different, the object layout is different, the standard library implementations are totally different...

Comment: Weird, it looks like the guy that made the binding is using clang

Comment: They say clang on Windows can be made compatible with MSVC but I'm not familiar with this mode of operation. Try clang-cl as the compiler (with cl-style command line options).

Comment: I do have the same errors in visual studio

Comment: You need to link it against openvr_api.dll. You may have destroyed it with --out-implib,openvr_api.dll option.

Comment: I managed to compile it with g++ but now I don't find the functions from my header file ^^'

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a lot of errors coming from your linker.
Make sure you link to your dependencies properly.

[What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Why is there a dot after the L?

Comment: Because the dll to include is in the same directory